# Get AutoCAD Block Handle - Differing Results w/ Attout VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, autocad, autocad-plugin

I have an attribute tab delimited text file that I want to apply to multiple drawings. In order for AutoCAD to NOT pop up and say "One or more blocks could not be found, do you want to select the data interactively?" , I have to use the HANDLE property of the block. On a given drawing, if I use ATTOUT to see the Handle of my block, I get a value such as '8B3F. Using ATTIN with that Handle works. Applying this to multiple drawings that have different handles, I have to get the handle for each block if each drawing. Here is my code - writing the handle to an excel doc.

```
            xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(attInText,, False)
            xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets(dwgName)

            Dim Handle As String = ""
            'get the handle to the CHS11x17TB title block
            For Each blk As AutoCAD.AcadBlock In cadDOC.Blocks
                If blk.Name.ToUpper = "CHS11X17TB" Then
                    Handle = blk.Handle
                    xlsheet.Cells(2, "A").value = Handle
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
```

Now, the problem is that the Handle is NOT the same as the one generated using ATTOUT - I'll get something like '75B0 using the code. Why do you think ATTOUT gives me a different handle than looping through the blocks of the drawing? I would note that my block is in paperspace, if that makes any difference. If that question cannot be answered, I'm interested in any alternative solutions for getting the handle to my block.

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the block definitions or the block references? `AutoCAD.AcadBlock` is the definition. There will be one definition per block and possibly multiple BlockReferences for each block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing block definition (Block) contained in the block table (Blocks) and block reference (BlockReference) inserted in the ModelSpace or PaperSpace.
Here's a not tested snippet which serac for a block reference in the model space (you can replace ModelSpace with PaperSpace to search the active paper space.

```
        xlbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(attInText,, False)
        xlsheet = xlbook.Worksheets(dwgName)

        Dim Handle As String = ""
        'get the handle to the CHS11x17TB title block
        For Each obj As AutoCAD.AcadObject In cadDOC.ModelSpace
            If obj.ObjectName = "AcDbBlockReference" Then
                If obj.EffectiveName.ToUpper = "CHS11X17TB" Then
                    Handle = obj.Handle
                    xlsheet.Cells(2, "A").value = Handle
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses! It was a lack of understanding on my part about blocks and block references.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to make it work. The block reference I wanted was in the paperspace. Note that EntityType 7 is an AcadBlockReference.

```
      Dim Handle As String = ""
            Dim count As Integer
            count = cadDOC.PaperSpace.Count

            Dim newObjs(count) As AutoCAD.AcadEntity
            Dim index As Integer

            For index = 0 To count - 1
                newObjs(index) = cadDOC.PaperSpace.Item(index)
            Next

            For i = 0 To count - 1
                Try
                    If newObjs(i).EntityType = 7 Then
                        Dim blk As AutoCAD.AcadBlockReference = newObjs(i)
                        If blk.Name.ToUpper = "CHS11X17TB" Then
                            Handle = "'" & blk.Handle
                        End If

                    End If
                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try


            Next
```